# A paper size 25 double-spaced single-column pages with font no less than 10 (including any tables and figures)

Tags: fonts

In fact I want to modify this paper so that it can suit 25 double-spaced single-column pages with font no less than 10 (including any tables and figures). Here is the code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}


\title{Title of the paper hipilihoplaaa}

\author{Author 1\corref{cor}}
\ead{name@gmail.com}
\author{Author 2\corref{}}
\author{Author 3\corref{}}


\address{adress of the university}

\cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}




\begin{abstract}
elsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates can be used by academics 
to write and submit journal articles to all Elsevier journals. There are 
presently over 2,700 journals published by Elsevier with over 250,000 
articles published per year. Popular journals include Cell, The Lancet, 
Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology but a complete list of all 
Elsevier journals can be found here. Elsevier explicitly state that this 
class and templates are their preferred format for articles submitted to all 
of their journals.lsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates can be 
used by academics to write and submit journal articles to all Elsevier 
journals. There are presently over 2,700 journals published by Elsevier with 
over 250,000 articles published per year. Popular journals include Cell, The 
Lancet, Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology but a complete list 
of all Elsevier journals can be found here. Elsevier explicitly state that 
this class and templates are their preferred format for articles submitted t 
o all of their journals.lsevier’s elsarticle document class and templates 
can be used by academics to write and submit journal articles to all 
Elsevier journals. There are presently over 2,700 journals published by 
Elsevier with over 250,000 articles published per year. Popular journals 
include Cell, The Lancet, Lancet Infectious Diseases and Lancet Neurology 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword} keyword1, keyword 2,  keyword 3,  keyword 4,  keyword 5.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to submit this? Then don't touch formatting, they'll do.

Comment: They send me comments about that

Comment: Did they say your paper is too long?  Whether it is is 12 normal pages or 10 reformatted pages, it is still too long.

Comment: Here is what they said : The maximum allowed paper size is 25 double-spaced single-column pages with font no less than 10 (including any tables and figures). Pages must be numbered.               
 I avoid it during the first revision but they insisted on that

Comment: Most journals will take what you give them, apply their own formatting, and then look at the length.  Any formatting changes you make will therefore be lost, and they'll again tell you to shorten the paper.  Editing your submission is a more reliable approach.